# Please Check My Proof of Well-Ordering Principle using Induction

Tags: induction, set-theory, well-orders

Well-Ordering Principle: $\exists m \in A[\forall n \in A (m \in n \vee m = n) ]$ for all $A \subseteq w$ where $w$ is the set of natural numbers and $A \neq \phi$.

Base Case: $A_{1} = \{ e_{1} \}$ is trivially true.

Induction Hypothesis: Let $A_{n} = \{ e_{1}, ..., e_{n} \}$ which has a smallest element, $e_{l}$.

Suppose $A_{n+1} = \{ e_{1}, ..., e_{n+1} \}$ where $A_{n+1} = A_{n} \cup \{e_{n+1}\} $.

By Trichotomy Law, 1) $e_{l} \in e_{n+1}$, or 2) $e_{l} = e_{n+1}$ or 3) $e_{n+1} \in e_{l}$.

If 1), $e_{l}$ continues to be the smallest element of $A_{n+1}$.

If 2), $A_{n} = A_{n+1}$ where $e_{l}$ is the smallest element.

If 3), as $\in$ is transitive, $e_{n+1} \in e_{i}$ for $\forall e_{i} \in A_{n} $ while being equal to itself. Therefore $e_{n+1}$ is the smallest of $A_{n+1}$.

Therefore, all subsets of $w$ has a smallest element. $\Box$

Comment: It’s a bit circular to prove well ordering with induction. As far as I’m aware, the validity of induction as a method of proof relies on the well ordering principle or variants

Comment: This proof only works for finite sets $A$.

Comment: @FShrike That’s completely wrong , Induction is embedded in the definition of the natural numbers

Comment: Succession is embedded, yes @Lobic but there are several posts on this site asserting the validity of induction as a method of proof as a corollary of the well ordering principle. Like I said, "as far as I'm aware". I too thought that induction was natural and inherent in $\Bbb N$'s construction, but then I read otherwise

Comment: @FShrike $\mathbb{N}$ is literally defined as the smallest inductive set.

Comment: @Mark Kamsma what would be the implications of that?

Comment: @WeiMinn Well, that you haven't proved that _all_ subsets $A$ of the naturals have a minimum.